# Use icon in jqGrid column header?

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I want to use the jQuery UI icon **ui-icon-comment** as a column header in one of my columns. Is there a way to do that?

Alternatively, if that's not possible, is there a way to use a PNG image in the header?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Items from `colNames` array can contain any HTML fragments: So you can place for example the following  text as the column header:

```html
"<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-comment' style='display:inline-block'/>"
```

I think that it will do what you need.